# Printing a rectangle of asterisks in Java

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, asterisk

The following is the source code to print a rectangle entirely composed of asterisks (*), with a test class included as well.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane ;

/**
 * A class to print block rectangles.
 */
class RectanglePrinter
{
    // instance var's
    int height ;            // height of rectangle (i.e. number of segments)    
    int width ;             // width of each segment(i.e. number of "*"s printed) 

    /**
     * Create a RectanglePrinter object.
     * @param height height of rectangle (i.e., number of lines to print)
     * @param width width of rectangle (i.e., number of '*'s per line
     */
    public RectanglePrinter(int height, int width)  // constructor
    {
        this.height = height ;
        this.width = width ;
    }

    /**
     * Prints one line of a rectangle, by printing exactly "width" asterisks
     */ 
    public void printSegment()
    {
        // write the body of this method here


    }

    /**
     * Prints a rectangle exactly "height" lines in height.  Each line is 
     * printed via a call to method printSegment
     */ 
    public void printRectangle()
    {
        System.out.println("Printing a " + height + " x " + width + " rectangle:") ;
        // write the body of this method here


    }

}  // end of class rectanglePrinter definition

public class RectanglePrinterTest
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog
                                   ("What is the height of the rectangle?") ;
        int height = Integer.parseInt(input) ;

        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog
                            ("What is the width of the rectangle?") ;

        int width = Integer.parseInt(input) ;

        RectanglePrinter r = new RectanglePrinter(height, width) ;

        System.out.println() ;
        r.printRectangle() ;
        System.out.println() ;
    }
}
```

In the segments where it says to fill out the method body, I was instructed to use for loops to print out the asterisks. I think I have a basic idea of how to do the printSegment() method:

```
for (int w = 1; w <= width; w++)
            {
                System.out.println("*");
            }
```

But from there, I am unsure of what to do within the printRectangle method. Judging from the comments in the code, I think I'm supposed to write a for loop in the printRectangle method that calls the printSegment method, except I don't think you can call a void method within the body of another method. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Update:

I attempted to use the following code within the body of printRectangle()

```
for (int h = 1; h <= height; h++)
                {
                    printSegment();
                }
```

After running the code and inputting the height and width, I received the following output:

```
Printing a 6 x 7 rectangle:
*

*

*

*

*

*

*

*

*

*

*

*

*

*

*

*

*

*

*

*

*

*

*

*

*

*

*

*

*

*

*

*

*

*

*

*

*

*

*

*

*
```

Now I can print out the asterisks at least, so I just need to know how to modify the code so the output is a rectangular block of asterisks.

Update #2.

I figured out the solution. Here's the code that got me the result I was looking for.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane ;

/**
 * A class to print block rectangles.
 */
class RectanglePrinter
{
    // instance var's
    int height ;            // height of rectangle (i.e. number of segments)    
    int width ;             // width of each segment(i.e. number of "*"s printed) 

    /**
     * Create a RectanglePrinter object.
     * @param height height of rectangle (i.e., number of lines to print)
     * @param width width of rectangle (i.e., number of '*'s per line
     */
    public RectanglePrinter(int height, int width)  // constructor
    {
        this.height = height ;
        this.width = width ;
    }

    /**
     * Prints one line of a rectangle, by printing exactly "width" asterisks
     */ 
    public void printSegment()
    {
        // write the body of this method here
                for (int w = 1; w <= width; w++)
                {
                    for (int h = 1; h <= height; h++)
                    {
                        System.out.print("*");
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                }


    }

    /**
     * Prints a rectangle exactly "height" lines in height.  Each line is 
     * printed via a call to method printSegment
     */ 
    public void printRectangle()
    {
        System.out.println("Printing a " + height + " x " + width + " rectangle:") ;
        // write the body of this method here
                printSegment();


    }

}  // end of class rectanglePrinter definition

public class RectanglePrinterTest
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog
                                   ("What is the height of the rectangle?") ;
        int height = Integer.parseInt(input) ;

        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog
                            ("What is the width of the rectangle?") ;

        int width = Integer.parseInt(input) ;

        RectanglePrinter r = new RectanglePrinter(height, width) ;

        System.out.println() ;
        r.printRectangle() ;
        System.out.println() ;
    }
}
```

The differences made: I added a nested for loop in the body of the printSegment() method, and instead of using
`System.out.println("*");` , used `System.out.print("*")` in the innermost loop, and `System.out.println()` in the outer loop, which resulted in the following output for the input of 5 x 7:

```
Printing a 5 x 7 rectangle:
*****
*****
*****
*****
*****
*****
*****
```

Comment: "I don't think you can call a void method within the body of another method".  What you think is wrong.

Comment: You can call a `void` method from inside another method. Go ahead and try doing what you think you're supposed to. You're on the right track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does indeed sound like you are supposed to make a loop in `printRectangle` where you call `printSegment` for height amount times.

To call your `printSegment` method inside `printRectangle` simply write `printSegment();` to call it.

Since its in the same class this is all you have to do to call it. If it were called from another class you can check how `RectanglePrinterTest` main method calls `printRectangle` using `r.printRectangle();` where `r` is an instance of the `RectanglePrinter` class.

As its a void method it wont return anything so you don't need to do anything else. :)

So to sum it up you are on the right track! Keep going and just try what you think feels right and you will surely figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the "\n" string to print a new line. It should print the "\n" every time the width or row command is completed.

Answer (score 0):

Using pieces of your code I can now successfully print a rectangle, horizontally.

The Helsinki CS MOOC (http://mooc.cs.helsinki.fi/) presented this task in its learn Java course.

```
public class MoreStars {

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        printRectangle(10, 6);
    }

    public static void printRectangle(int width, int height) {
        int i;
        int j;
        for ( i = 0; i < height; i++ ) {
            for ( j = 0; j < width; j++) {
                printStars(width);
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }                
    }

    public static void printStars(int amount) {   
        System.out.print(" * ");
    }
}
```